# OMS Agent not heart beating with error certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)

Tags: linux, openssl

On an Ubuntu 20 machine, OMS Agent not heart beating. In the OMS Agent log, we have the below error message.

```
Error sending the telemetry request to OMS agent management service: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

The openssl is customized on the box. Few steps are not configured while upgrading openssl but I verified that should not be the issue.

```
$ openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022)
built on: Thu Dec 22 14:25:22 2022 UTC
platform: linux-x86_64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(int) blowfish(ptr)
compiler: gcc -fPIC -pthread -m64 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -O3 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAESNI_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DNDEBUG
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/local/lib/
```

If we use `root` user, we are able to connect to ODS endpoint and bing.com without any issues using openssl client.
But if we use `omsagent` user, we are not running into the same problem connecting to ODS endpoint and bing.com with opensssl client.

I verified that the `/etc/ssl/certs` has the proper certs configured.

Comment: More information:
`omsagent@$ echo | openssl s_client -connect bing.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = US, O = Microsoft Corporation, CN = Microsoft RSA TLS CA 02
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = www.bing.com
verify return:1`

Comment: `$ ls -l /usr/local/ssl
total 40
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    14 Dec 22 14:43 certs -> /etc/ssl/certs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   412 Dec 22 14:27 ct_log_list.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   412 Dec 22 14:27 ct_log_list.cnf.dist
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Dec 22 14:27 misc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10909 Dec 22 14:27 openssl.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10909 Dec 22 14:27 openssl.cnf.dist
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Dec 22 14:27 private`